# Ruby convert string formatted as multidimensional array, to actual Array

Tags: ruby, multidimensional-array

I have a string in Ruby:

```
[[nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,'Average of','Transaction Amount','dataset_test_3.SampleData100'],[nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,'Country','dataset_test_3.SampleData100']]
```

It is formatted perfectly as a multidimensional Array, and has 2 sub-arrays. (in some cases, it may have 3).

How can I create an actual Array out of this?

Appreciate any directions, have been look for a while on this to no avail whatsoever.

Comment: When supplying data, please reduce it to the bare minimum necessary to reproduce the problem you're seeing. Anything else beyond that is a waste of our time. Your question sounds like an XY question, where you're asking about question Y, when you should be asking about X. How did you get that string representation of the an array? That's very rare and usually is the result of trying to use the output of `inspect` or capturing a `puts`-type output.

Comment: If you could use a neutral format like JSON your life would be a lot easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use YAML to parse your string into an array

```
require 'yaml'

array = YAML.load(input)
array.flatten 
# => ["nil", "nil", "nil", "nil", "nil", "nil", "nil", "nil", "nil", "Average of", "Transaction Amount", "dataset_test_3.SampleData100", "nil", "nil", "nil", "nil", "nil", "nil", "nil", "nil", "nil", "nil", "Country", "dataset_test_3.SampleData100"]
```

Comment: Almost! If I do this though, the nil values in my string remain strings. I've tried to make them nil with gsub, like below, but it given an error.

    array.each do |s|
    s.gsub('\"nil\"',nil)
    end

Comment: Still brilliant to this day! I was passing a 2D array of integers via CLI to another process, and as long as I planted the entire array into a single string, this was the perfect method for converting it back to an array of integers. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

The answer for your question is `eval()`.

You can use `eval()` to evaluate a string as "code" in ruby.

For example, in your case, if you have this string called `input`, which contains an array declaration then:

```
b = eval(input)
b # => [[nil,nil,nil,'Average of',....]]
```

Here is a great introduction for `eval()` from RubyMonk:

http://rubymonk.com/learning/books/5-metaprogramming-ruby-ascent/chapters/24-eval/lessons/63-eval

And after `eval()`, you can use `flatten` on your array, to flat it out to a one dimension one.

So, in short, `eval(input).flatten` would do the job. :) ( as [Nimir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/903842/nimir) suggested)

It's also worth noting this can be **extremely dangerous** to do on untrusted data. **DO NOT** ever evaluate arbitrary user data. (by [tadman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87189/tadman) )

Comment: My string is named "input". If I do input.flatten, I get this error: undefined method `flatten' for #<String:0x00000000fdceb0> (NoMethodError)

Comment: You can't `flatten` a String.

Comment: It's also worth noting this can be **extremely dangerous** to do on untrusted data. **DO NOT** ever evaluate arbitrary user data.